# Evil maids in the server room

Tags: encryption, linux, privacy, ssh

I am well aware of the fact that physical insecurity in principle means no security. But let´s say I own a root server with full disk encryption which is unlocked/booted via dropbear ssh. In which ways can an attacker with physical access (e.g. the hosting provider) gain access to my data and what countermeasures can I take to prevent the attacks or to slow him down? He could retrieve the encryption keys from the RAM. [Tresor](http://www1.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/tresor/) stores the key in CPU registers and this might mitigate the risk. But I guess the usage of tresor is also detectable. The attacker might modify the boot partition or kernel. Is it possible to perform a checksum over the network of /boot in order to determine someone has tampered with it? Maybe colocation in combination with TPM could help? Also [Mandos](http://www.recompile.se/mandos/man/intro.8mandos) and homomorphic encryption (though it might take some years to be practically usable) could be useful. Any more ideas for implementing attacks and protection against them?

Answer (score 5):

The most common solution to this is to create physical security: you have a dedicated rack, and use a secure, lockable cabinet.

You can also create physical security for a single box by locking the case. There are some subtleties to getting this right: securing the BIOS, firewire ports, etc.

Disk encryption is an effective technique, although it is susceptible to advanced attacks. Remote boot techniques like dropbear are vulnerable to a remote variant of the evil maid attack. For example, someone with physical access could tamper with the dropbear partition, and have it leak the key on the next reboot.

TPM-based disk encryption could work well. It doesn't require a password on boot, but instead only reveals the encryption key to a trusted boot image. I've not seen this done on a server, but I think it would work. I expect an advanced attacker can get around this too.

An attacker with physical access can only read RAM if they are quite highly skilled - at least, assuming you secure the basics like firewire. Given advanced attackers have other routes in, I don't think Tresor buys you much. Mandos sounds like an automated way of supplying the boot password remotely; I expect it has the same risks as dropbear.

Ultimately, to make proper decisions you need to consider the threat profile of a specific system. In practice, if you don't trust your hosting provider, maybe the best option is to switch to one you do trust - even if this means bringing your data centre in-house.